# How to check used SSD?

Tags: ssd

I gonna buy used Samsung Evo 850 250 GB. How to check its condition ? There is some information about it:

[image]

Comment: If its in a box, and the production date's Jan this year, can't have been used all that much...

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with "condition". Do you want to check if it is used? Do you want to check the health of the SSD? Please be specific.

Comment: install Windows and use [tools like CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) to check the drive.

Comment: about health. It's not mine. I can't install windows.

Comment: I have laptop to insert and live cd

Answer (score 1):

Use the Samsung Magician software provided by Samsung.

> Reaching the maximum potential and proficiency of your Samsung SSD is
>   easy. With the advanced Magician software, an exclusive set of
>   essential tools equip you like a pro. Stay ahead with automatic
>   updates, check drive health and speed, and enable speed boosting RAPID
>   Mode, all with one simple download.

http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/magician/